# Type extensions won't compile and/or exhibit strange compile-time behavior

Tags: f#, extension-methods, typeerror, overloading

*EDIT: I've meanwhile [reported this](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1940) to the F# team. Though not receiving an answer does not necessarily mean this is a bug, I've reassessed my own question below and at least parts of it don't make sense. Feel free to correct me ;).*

---

A workaround for the following issue is trivial, but I'm interested in what causes the behavior which I think is best explained by showing some progressive examples:

All examples have the following:

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module SystemExt =
    open System

    let parseInt = Int64.TryParse

    type Option<'T> with
        /// Creates an Option from a .NET byref result, (true, res) -> Some res, otherwise None
        static member ofByRef (success, result) =
            match success with
            | true -> Some result
            | _ -> None
```

#### First example:

```
type Int64 with
    static member TryParse = parseInt >> Option.ofByRef

let test1 = 
    Int64.TryParse "42"
    |> Option.map ((*) 2L)  // won't compile, type error
```

#### Second example:

Different syntax, redundant repetition of parameter, but this compiles, where the previous example doesn't:

```
type Int64 with
    static member TryParse s = (parseInt >> Option.ofByRef) s

let test1 = 
    Int64.TryParse "42"
    |> Option.map ((*) 2L)  // compiles fine
```

#### Third example:

I was a little surprised this compiles, but perhaps the first is compiled into a property, the second into a method, so perhaps that explains it (though typically two functions with different signatures is normally invalid).

```
type Int64 with
    static member TryParse = parseInt >> Option.ofByRef
    static member TryParse s = (parseInt >> Option.ofByRef) s

let test1 = 
    Int64.TryParse "42"
    |> Option.map ((*) 2L)
```

#### Fourth example:

I can't explain this one, the difference is only in the first line, using the original function `Int64.TryParse`.

```
type Int64 with
    static member TryParse = Int64.TryParse >> Option.ofByRef
    static member TryParse s = (parseInt >> Option.ofByRef) s  // type error

let test1 = 
    Int64.TryParse "42" 
    |> Option.map ((*) 2L)  // type error
```

#### Fifth example, same as first, but calling it differently;

```
let test1 = 
    Int64.get_TryParse() "42"   // compiles fine, why the need to be 
                                // explicit using the property accessor?
    |> Option.map ((*) 2L)
```

#### Sixth example:

This one was my starting point, which led to the other experiments above, I still don't "get" this one.

```
type Int64 with        
    static member TryParse = Int64.TryParse >> Option.ofByRef

let test1 = 
    Int64.TryParse "42"
    |> Option.map ((*) 2L)   // type error
```

#### Seventh example:

Variant of the sixth example

```
type Int64 with        
    static member TryParse s = (Int64.TryParse >> Option.ofByRef) s // type error

let test1 = 
    Int64.TryParse "42"  // type error
    |> Option.map ((*) 2L)
```

The last example (the seventh) seems to incorrectly infer the type of the `Int64.TryParse` method and ends up calling itself recursively, leading to the type error.

I don't see why this should happen, the order of resolution is, iirc, that class members go before extensions and in cases of ambiguity, members take precedence.

The difference between the sixth and seventh is odd. The extension line compiles in the sixth, but not in the seventh. Though there is no standard way of ever calling the overriding `TryParse` method of the sixth example.